# PC inventory system that does not rely on WMI

Tags: windows, networking, wmi

I'm looking for a software that can make an inventory of the PCs on your network for an SMB environment. I know ther are plenty (Spiceworks, LanSweeper, etc). But they all rely on WMI to function. The problem is I have so many problems with getting WMI to work on all workstations that I'm looking for a more reliable alternative.

Do you know of any affordable (or better free) inventory tool that uses a client on the workstation that contacts a local workstation or server to give an update of it's situation?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Kind Regards,

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic, per the [faq].

Answer (score 3):

Check out OCS Inventory

http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/en/

Answer (score 2):

You could use SNMP, but it's not going to work as well...

A more important question is Why isn't WMI working?!  I've run sites with thousands of clients, and WMI has been instrumental in maintaining those environments.  Further, I have only rarely seen WMI "just break."

I would make every possible case in making fixing that widespread problem a high priority.  If it comes from a forced configuration from your client image or Group Policy, it should be able to be fixed easily.  Otherwise, you'll actually need to troubleshoot and distribute a fix.  (Fortunately, you can often use GP to do this.)

Comment: It seems to be either problems with the firewall or WMI repository. I followed the how-to document of troubleshooting WMI problems in Spiceworks but I can't get them all to work.

Comment: Then find someone who can and do a beginner course to windows system administration please.